# Magento Custom Sitemap

Tags: php, magento, sitemap

Magento's default sitemap generation produces an XML file that displays all products, including simple products that are associated with configurable products. I only want the configurable product not the associated simple products, can anyone help me?

In Mage/Sitemap/Model/Sitemap.php the function that generates the XML sitemap is generateXml() and the code block that generates the product urls is:

```
$changefreq = (string)Mage::getStoreConfig('sitemap/product/changefreq', $storeId);
$priority   = (string)Mage::getStoreConfig('sitemap/product/priority', $storeId);
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sitemap/catalog_product')->getCollection($storeId);
foreach ($collection as $item) {
    $xml = sprintf('<url><loc>%s</loc><lastmod>%s</lastmod><changefreq>%s</changefreq><priority>%.1f</priority></url>',
    htmlspecialchars($baseUrl . $item->getUrl()),
    $date,
    $changefreq,
    $priority
    );
    $io->streamWrite($xml);
}
unset($collection);
```

I tried using

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

and changed this line:

```
htmlspecialchars($baseUrl . $item->getUrl()),
```

to this line to get it work

```
htmlspecialchars($item->getProductUrl()),
```

I get the correct products (without the associated ones), but the urls are like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/catalog/product/view/id/532/
```

I want the Url Rewrites, so i changed it to:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection($storeId)
->addUrlRewrite();
```

But i still get this:

```
http://www.domain.com/catalog/product/view/id/532/
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can try with below code.

```
$product_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', 16)->addUrlRewrite();
echo $product_collection->getFirstItem()->getProductUrl();
```

or you can load url separately as you already have product collection than try something like this

```
Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'attribute_code', Mage::app()->getStore());
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately i don't get the desired result